# Match dplyr condition but return alternate option

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks like the below:

```
   Name round  MatchNumber Score
       <chr> <int> <int> <dbl>
     1 A         1     1    48
     2 B         1     1    66
     3 C         1     2    74
     4 D         1     2    62
     5 E         1     3    61
     6 F         1     3    63
     7 G         1     4    63
     8 H         1     4    63
```

I now want to create a new column `Opponent` that, in each row, contains the opposing `Name`. My anticipated answer would look like:

```
Name round  MatchNumber Score Opponent
   <chr> <int> <int> <dbl> <chr>
 1 A         1     1    48    B
 2 B         1     1    66    A
 3 C         1     2    74    D
 4 D         1     2    62    C
 5 E         1     3    61    F
 6 F         1     3    63    E
 7 G         1     4    63    H
 8 H         1     4    63    G
```

I have tried:

```
      ExampleData %>%
      group_by(round, MatchNumber) %>%
      mutate(Opponent = case_when(MatchNumber == MatchNumber ~ Name))
```

Except, of course I end up with the first match! Is there any way to get the second option for a match? This seems really simple but I cannot get my head around it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of `dplyr::first` and `dplyr::last` this could be achieved like so:

```r
library(dplyr)

ExampleData %>%
  group_by(round, MatchNumber) %>%
  mutate(Opponent = ifelse(Name == first(Name), last(Name), first(Name)))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 6
#> # Groups:   round, MatchNumber [4]
#>     row Name  round MatchNumber Score Opponent
#>   <int> <chr> <int>       <int> <int> <chr>   
#> 1     1 A         1           1    48 B       
#> 2     2 B         1           1    66 A       
#> 3     3 C         1           2    74 D       
#> 4     4 D         1           2    62 C       
#> 5     5 E         1           3    61 F       
#> 6     6 F         1           3    63 E       
#> 7     7 G         1           4    63 H       
#> 8     8 H         1           4    63 G
```

Comment: I never knew about `dplyr::first` and `dplyr::last` so thank you for teaching me something!